# Zohar and Maharal on the soul and face

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul, zohar, face, maharal

1) I heard from someone say in the name Zohar haKadosh that the eyes are the "mirror to the soul" - that to those who are able to read such things a person's eyes are very revealing.

Does anyone know where the *Zohar* says this?

2) I read somewhere in the *Maharal* that the word Panim (face) is in the plural because the face is the meeting point of the inner dimension of a person and the outer dimension. That is why it is your face that reveals your emotions because the emotions come from within a person.

Does anyone know where the *Maharal* says this?

Comment: mishle המים הפנים לפנים כן לב האדם לאדם

Answer (score 3):

See Zohar on parashat Yitro, in [Zohar 73a](http://%20Zohar%2073a).

For example:

> עיינין צהיבין ירוקין, שגעונא אית ביה, ובגין שגעוניה איהו פום ממלל רברבן, ועביד גרמיה כבר נש רב ברברבנו...
>
> 90. IF his eyes are yellowish-green, he has madness about him, and because of this madness his mouth speaks in a bombastic manner, and he carries a self-importance about himself...

I don't know where the Maharal says this.

Comment: I clicked the link and it didn't go through. Please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

[Rav Yitzchok Hutner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Hutner) says that the פנים (face) reveals what is בפנים (inside). The face reveals your inner emotions. Rav Hutner was an avid scholar on the Maharal's works.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, yosefkorn! This answer would be much improved with a source to your claim.